are Muslim women allowed to have intercourse with their slaves?
‏سلام عليكم
if muslim women who’s unmarried take on a slave can she have intercourse him? Also if Muslim woman married and she have a slave can she have intercourse with him?
‏جزاك الله خير

Would you really dare to even think about bringing curse upon your children, being born outside of proper marriage?

In the Old Testament, it is written "No one born of a forbidden marriage nor any of their descendants may enter the assembly of the LORD, not even in the tenth generation."

personally i wouldn’t do that because im am made of wedlock. But what does that mean? what did the child do? also if man can have intercourse with a woman slave, why can’t woman do the same? i don’t understand.

out of wedlock*

No, It is permissible as Men are regarded as Qawwam due to which she cannot have sexual intercourse with her own male slaves.
